# Receive messages from Azure Servicebus / IotHub

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk

I want to check the azure servicebus/iothub constantly for messages. However, when I do it like this I get the following error

**"An exception of type 'Amqp.AmqpException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Operation 'Receive' is not valid under state: End."**

Any ideas how I should implement constant pulling of messages and/or resolve this error?

```cs
var connection = new Connection(address);
var session = new Session(connection);
var entity = Fx.Format("/devices/{0}/messages/deviceBound", _deviceId);

var receiveLink = new ReceiverLink(session, "receive-link", entity);
while (true)
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);

    var message = await receiveLink.ReceiveAsync();
    if (message == null) continue;
    //else do things with message
 }
```

Comment: How do u authenticate? Do u put CBS token after establishing connection but before opening a session? Check it out: https://github.com/ppatierno/codesamples/blob/master/IoTHubAmqp/IoTHubAmqp/Program.cs

Answer (score 0):

From the endpoint you're using it looks like you're talking about receiving cloud-to-device (c2d) messages, in other words, the code you're writing runs on the device, and is meant to receive messages sent through the service to this device, right?

The simplest way of doing this is using the [DeviceClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.azure.devices.client.deviceclient.aspx) class of the [C# SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdks/tree/master/csharp/device). An example of how to use this class is provided in the [DeviceClientAmqpSample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdks/tree/master/csharp/device/samples/DeviceClientAmqpSample) project.

Once you create your `DeviceClient` instance using your device connection string, the `DeviceClient` class has a `ReceiveAsync` method that can be used to receive messages.

```cs
var deviceClient = DeviceClient.CreateFromConnectionString("<DeviceConnectionString>");
while(true)
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    var receivedMessage = await deviceClient.ReceiveAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
    if (receivedMessage != null)
    {
        var messageData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receivedMessage.GetBytes());
        Console.WriteLine("\t{0}> Received message: {1}", DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime(), messageData);
        await deviceClient.CompleteAsync(receivedMessage);
    }
}
```

Comment: The official Nuget package only works on Windows as far as I know. He uses AMQP.Net lite which runs on more platforms

Comment: There are Nuget packages for Xamarin now too (PCL). Works on Windows, iOS, Android, UWP and Windows Phone 8. AMQPNetlite indeed has support for even more platforms.

Comment: Yes, but those PCLs only support HTTP, as far as I know.

Comment: Helikaon is right. The Microsoft Azure libraries are not supported on mono (Raspberry). That's why I need to use AMQP.Net lite.